# Create cli numerated menu from list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list that all I want is a menu printed out of all the partitions that are stored in mylist. I would like it to look like this

```
1: /dev/sda0
2: /dev/sda1
3: /dev/sda2
etc....
```

This is what I have so far.

```
import pyudev

mylist = [device.devide_node for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='partitions')]

for x in mylist:
     print mylist[len(x)] + ': ' + mylist
```

I don't know how to format this to make it look like above

Comment: Aside: that code doesn't seem like it can work.  You don't make a `context` object, and you have a typo for `device_node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code:

```
for x in mylist:
    print mylist[len(x)]
```

Makes very little sense. `x` is an item in the list, `len(x)` is the length *of that item* (e.g. `len("/dev/sda0") == 9`), and you are trying to use that length as an index into the list. This is likely to lead to an `IndexError`, as there is no guarantee that `mylist[9]` exists!

I think you were trying to do something like:

```
for x in range(len(mylist)):
    print mylist[x]
```

where `x` would be a valid index for `mylist`, but it is much better to use `enumerate` for this type of process:

```
for num, device in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    print "{0}: {1}".format(num, device)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate`:

```
for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    print '{}: {}'.format(i+1, x)
```

Comment: Not that it matters much, but I tend to write `enumerate(mylist, 1)`.

Comment: You are both right, but I can only except one answer thanks to both of you.